# What does the '&' in 'operator++(int) &' operator overload means?

Tags: c++

What does the `&` after a method signature mean and do? I have this:

```cpp
Iterator operator++(int) &
```

in my iterator types but I do not recall why I had to put it there (only that it fixed the problem I had a while back). Strangely I cannot find much about it but it is most likely because I do not know how it is actually called.

A bonus question but is it part of the signature? If yes, how does the pointer to this method look like (where does the `&` go)?

EDIT: To answer the bonus question: It is part of the signature (and can be overload). Having ref-qualified signature means you cannot have non-ref qualified one though. And the pointer would be: `Iterator(Iterator::*ptr)(int) & = &Iterator::operator++;`

Comment: It's a reference [qualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) member function. Basically it means that the function can only be called on objects that can be an lvalue references.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes it does, thank you. Just to clarify as the link to cppreference nor the related question asnwers it - is it part of the function signature? (experimentally tested it seems not)

Comment: `const` and `volatile` qualification for member functions is part of the signature (that is you can overload on `const` and non-`const` qualification). I don't know about reference qualification, but the example shows overloading of lvalue- and rvalue-reference qualification so it must be part of the signature.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah right, it is a bit strange. You can overload on `&` and `&&` but then you cannot have the version without any ref-qualifiers (because it would be ambiguous and kind of nonsensical as non-ref-qualifed signature can bind to both). And for the curious the pointer would be (for my example in OP): `Iterator(Iterator::*ptr)(int) & = &Iterator::operator++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an lvalue-ref qualifier. It is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions).

> During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of class X is treated as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - lvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X

This means that the member function can only be used on an lvalue. In simpler but kind of imprecise terms, this prevents calling the function on a temporary.